# How to adjust height of SharePoint Lookup Field Multi-Select

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, spservices

I saw how to adjust multi select lookup field width (solution here: [How to adjust width of SharePoint Lookup Field Multi-Select](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27191951/How-to-adjust-width-of-SharePoint-Lookup-Field-Multi-Select.html)), but maybe anyone can tell me how to adjust height?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jQuery to adjust the width and height of the multi-select lookup field.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#<SelectCandidateId>").attr('style','width:370px;height:125px');
  $("#<SelectResultId>").attr('style','width:370px;height:125px');
});
</script>
```

Get the Ids of SelectCandidate element and SelectResult element using [F12 developer tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589512(v=vs.85).aspx#SelectByClick).

For example:
[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#multi_lookup_114c4415-9935-48a1-88e5-c0cb0c00a22a_SelectCandidate").attr('style','width:370px;height:125px');
  $("#multi_lookup_114c4415-9935-48a1-88e5-c0cb0c00a22a_SelectResult").attr('style','width:370px;height:125px');
});
</script>
```

[image]